# How can I copy files from Hyper-V Server to Guest System

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v

I installed stand-alon Hyper-V server and create 2 guest system. Now I need copy drivers for Ethernet controller. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you talking about the host ethernet controllers?  If its the host then just hitting windows update will give you the supported version of the drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods that allow you to mount a guest's Hyper-V VHD file in the host OS.  In Server 2008 R2 (and Windows 7), you can actually mount a VHD file as an attached drive in Disk Manager.  [image]

There are also third-party tools that allow you to open VHDs and edit the file systems inside of them.  R1Soft makes a tool that's free, although registration is required.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you don't need a 3rd party tool to mount and edit vhd's that are w2k8r2+ just use DISM.

Comment: Good point, Tony -- I was just pointing out that such tools DO exist.  I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. Best bet would be having a disc image. For windows server, just install the virtualization compontns (menu itm in connection application). Linus.... put possibly in a legcy network card, use it to download.

Alternatively make a disc image or vhd image with the files on it and attach it to the guest.